# Unique Columns with MySQL Union

Tags: mysql, sql, unions

I've got a mysql query that is returning the required data, but is not returning unique rows. How can I assure that only unique rows are returned?

**Here is my query**

```
SELECT  a.follow_id, a.user_id, a.following, b.donor_id, b.firstname, b.lastname, b.image
FROM followers a
INNER JOIN donors b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE following = 257

UNION DISTINCT 

SELECT  a.follow_id, a.user_id, a.following, b.donor_id, b.firstname, b.lastname, b.image
FROM followers a
INNER JOIN donors b ON a.following = b.user_id
WHERE a.user_id = 257
```

Which returns multiple results for a user_id. How can I make sure that the results are not doubled up, by user_id?

I have tried a group by, but I must be doing something wrong, cause I can't get it working.

The results I get back

```
**follow_id user_id following   donor_id    firstname   lastname**  image
13  224 257 124 Just    A Donor 224.jpg
11  257 224 124 Just    A Donor 224.jpg
9   257 222 116 Dummy   Donor   222.jpg
```

Got it...just had to group by donor_id

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT  a.follow_id, a.user_id, a.following, b.donor_id, b.firstname, b.lastname, b.image
FROM followers a
INNER JOIN donors b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE following = 257 

UNION DISTINCT 

SELECT  a.follow_id, a.user_id, a.following, b.donor_id, b.firstname, b.lastname, b.image
FROM followers a
INNER JOIN donors b ON a.following = b.user_id
WHERE a.user_id = 257 ) AS t
GROUP BY donor_id
```

Comment: Are you now saying you want just one row per user id?  That's different from the question you originally asked (and which 2 people answered).  How should the query decide which row to return, for any given user id?  For example, in the result set you gave, which of the two rows of the result should be returned for user_id 257?

Comment: When the user_id is the same (257) what would you want to show for the other columns (that are different as you show).  Best of all please show the **desired** output you want to see.  Thanks!

Comment: It should only return 1 row, per user_id. Sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: Sorry it should only return 1 row for each donor_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.follow_id, a.user_id, a.following, b.donor_id, b.firstname, b.lastname, b.image
FROM followers a
INNER JOIN donors b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE following = 257
```

Comment: Pretty sure it needs to be grouped by user_id

Comment: what happens when you add the grouped by to these queries?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT  a.follow_id, a.user_id, a.following, b.donor_id, b.firstname, b.lastname, b.image 
FROM followers a 
INNER JOIN donors b ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
WHERE following = 257 or a.user_id = 257
```

You can also try SELECT DISTINCT if the rows aren't unique within each half of the query.